# Delphi IDE weird source code formatting

Tags: delphi, ide, formatter

Sometimes after pressing some keys in Delphi IDE all functions headers become looking like this:

```
constructor TClient.Create(

  const AServer: TServer;

  const APhone: AnsiString);
```

It's a little annoying cause the code formatter (CTRL-D) cannot amend such code properly and I have to remove all line breaks manually. How does it happen?

Comment: Check your Formatter->Delphi->Line breaks settings if you are using the builtin formatter or the settings of any third party plugin (like GExperts). Also check the line endings of your code (with Notepad++ for example) - could be that you have some non Windows line breaks. Code editor does not like them very much.

Comment: No plugins, I use other editors very rarely and it's not the case. As per the formatter I use it very often and never see it ever did such formatting. And it happens in different delphi versions.

Comment: Are you using version control? Git for example can change line endings depending on settings.

Comment: Nope, no version control

Comment: My Delphi doesn't do this by default. Formats them on the same line with single spaces as expected, unless of course it reaches the max line, in which case it wraps to the next line, again as expected. Must be something non-standard set up in your installation.

Comment: *after pressing some keys*. What keys specifically? *all function headers* Do you mean all method declarations in the implementation section only, or in both interface and implementation? *it happens in different Delphi versions* Which versions specifically? Do you have any version where it doesn't happen? I work all day every day in Seattle, Berlin and D2007 (which uses the JEDI code formatter), and have never had this issue in any of them. You have absolutely no IDE plugins installed (GExperts, CNWizards, anything from JEDI, etc.)?

Comment: @KenWhite: something similar happens to me too, occasionally. It does happen after pressing some keys, probably the wrong key in a situation (I suspect the part of the editor that handles edit templates -- and that it gets the wrong key, e.g. a comma where a semicolon is expected). Since it was not the right key, it is almost impossible to tell which keys, unless you'd use something like a key logger. Doesn't happen a lot, so not enough to worry about. It can usually be undone anyway. In other words, the **sometimes** in OP's question is important here.

Comment: @Molochnik: Did you try a simple **undo** (IIRC, it must be undone *twice*, but it could be I don't remember it correctly <g>).

Comment: @Rudy: I was attempting to get enough detail to isolate the issue, so we could see if it was some combination of editor or formatter settings. Without being able to do so, chances of this question getting an answer are pretty slim (unless one of the EMBT dev team that works on the editor specifically happens to stop by and answer it).

Comment: @Rudy I always find it later than required for undo. Yes that doesn't happen a lot, but if it does it's really annoying if you have a lot of functions with a lot of parameters

Comment: @Ken Keys unknown. Delphi versions are XE2, XE7, Tokyo. All function headers in the implementation part, interface part is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found how it actually happens and can repeat these formatting results: you format the code with the specific sintax error, correct the code and then format it again. The example is here:

```
type
  TTableDesc = record
    constructor Create(););
  end;

  function func(const a: string; const b: Boolean; const c: pointer): string;
```

After the actions I mentioned above you'll get this:

```
type
  TTableDesc = record
    constructor Create();
  end;

function func(

  const a: string;

  const b: Boolean;

  const c: pointer): string;
```

The best way to avoid it is just not to format the code with errors.